# h5py stores only 0s in datasets

Tags: python, h5py

I'm trying to store some values in an h5py file, but every time I try to store a matrix in a dataset, all the matrix elements are replaced by 0s. Here's an example

I create the file like this:

```
output_file=h5py.File('output_file', 'w')

dset=output_file.create_dataset('dset', (3,3))

for k in range(3):
    for l in range(3):
        dset[k][l]=1.
```

I then read the file and try to print the output

```
file=h5py.File('output_file', 'r')

print(file['dset'][:])
```

the output is

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

all the 1s have been turned into 0s. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explicitly [covered in the manual](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#multiple-indexing). When you do `dset[k]`, you create a temporary array. It is this array's `l`'th element that you set when you do `dset[k][l] = 1.0`. That temporary array is not the h5py dataset that you want to be referring to – you aren't touching the latter at all.

In short: index with `dset[k, l]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
dset[k,l]=matrix[k][l]
```

instead.